# Input in c language

Tags: c, input, output, scanf

Why I am not able to take 3rd input of character in my c - program??

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    float f1;
    scanf("%f",&f1);
    char ch;
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    printf("Integer %d\nfloat %f\ncharacter %c",a,f1,ch);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%c",&ch);
```

After entering the `float` value and pressing `enter`, the `scanf` reads that extra newline character `\n`. To prevent that use this:

```
scanf(" %c",&ch);
```

Space before `%c` reads that extra `\n` and the required character will be stored in `ch`.

To demonstrate that please see the code below :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    float f1;
    scanf("%f", &f1);
    char ch;
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    printf("Integer %d\nfloat %f\ncharacter %d", a, f1, ch); // changed to %d to print ASCII value
}
```

The output is :

```
12
12.3
Integer 12
float 12.300000
character 10
```

You can see the output here, it prints 10 (ASCII of `\n`).

**Solution** :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    float f1;
    scanf("%f", &f1);
    char ch;
    scanf(" %c", &ch);
    printf("Integer %d\nfloat %f\ncharacter %c", a, f1, ch);
}
```

The output :

```
12
12.3
k
Integer 12
float 12.300000
character k
```